# Replace all matched strings with modified substring

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Actually, I want to replace all matched string used as a key of given object to find the value using javascript regular expression.
For example:
we have string as

> hello,how are you???!!OH!! i am fine. what about you, !!FRIEND!!? I am !!GOOD!!.

and object is like
var mapper={"OH":"oh+","FRIEND":"friend+","GOOD":"good+"}

Then output should be like:

> hello,how are you???OH+ i am fine. what about you, FRIEND+? I am GOOD+.

As starting and ending !! sign will be replaced with **only** + sign in the end.

```js
var mapper={"OH":"oh+","FRIEND":"friend+","GOOD":"good+"};
data=data.replace(new RegExp("!![A-Z]*!!", 'g'),modifiedSubstring);
```

I am new to use regular expression but tried some code as placed above. In this expression what should I write instead of `modifiedSubstring`.

Comment: You only replaced ending `!!` with a `+`.

Comment: no, it will match uppercase words starts and end with !!. then replace all of them with + appending in last

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `RegExp` `/(\!+(?=[A-Z]+))|(\!+(?=\s|\?|\.|$))/g` to match multiple `!` characters followed by capital letters , or multiple `!` characters followed by space character, `.` character or end of input. Replace first capture group with `""` empty string, replace second capture group with `+` character

```js
var data = "hello,how are you???!!OH!! i am fine. what about you, "
           + "!!FRIEND!!? I am !!GOOD!!.";

data = data.replace(/(\!+(?=[A-Z]+))|(\!+(?=\s|\?|\.|$))/g
             , function(match, p1, p2) {
                 return p1 ? "" : "+" 
           });

document.body.innerHTML = data;
```

Comment: what if i want to match the uppercase word with a given object key and return the value. e.g var mapper={"OH":"oh+","FRIEND":"friend+"};

Comment: @gurvk Yes, that should be possible. Though `RegExp` at solution above matches `!!` characters, not uppercase letters . Original Question did not include mapping matches to object ?

Comment: hey, but it adds a line break after replacing that content. can you help me out from this problem?

Comment: @gurvk A line break should not be added to replacement string. Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the data inside the desired pattern and return it with your desired formatting by using parentheses and $1

```
    data = "hello,how are you???!!OH!! i am fine. what about you, !!FRIEND!!? I am !!GOOD!!.";

    data=data.replace(new RegExp("!!([A-Z]*)!!", 'g'),"$1+");
```

Comment: it is working in old case without using object mapper. how it will work with mapper object. i tried using mapper["$1"] instead of ["$1"]

Comment: object related problem solved with the help of replacement using function.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for instances like `!!word!!` and replace it to `word+` using this regex.

**Regex:** `!!([A-Z]*?)!!`

**Explanation:**

- It will match `!!` followed by a `WORD` followed by `!!`.

**Replacement to do:**

- `\1+` This will replace the match with just `WORD+` as `WORD` falls in first captured group.

### **<kbd>[Regx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC6lK9/3)</kbd>**